# Flattening before Fully-connected Layer (DENSE)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, matrix

Can anyone explain why we need to flatten the data before inputting it into a fully-connected layer? What will happen if we input a matrix of size (m,n) into a fully-connected layer that has k activation units?

I recently tried to input a matrix of X (126976,4) to a DENSE layer with 255 neurons and got the weight matrix of (4,255), which I can't explain why? My training output Y is the size (126976,255).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

- In a fully connected layer, also known as a dense layer, each neuron is connected to every neuron in the previous layer. This means that each neuron receives an input from all the neurons in the previous layer.
- When you input a matrix of size (m,n) into a fully-connected layer, the layer expects a 1D array as input. This is because the weights of the fully connected layer are also a 1D array. If you input a 2D array (or matrix), the layer will not be able to correctly compute the dot product between the input and the weights.
- Flattening the data converts the 2D array into a 1D array, which can then be correctly processed by the fully connected layer.
- In your case, you input a matrix of size (126976,4) into a dense layer with 255 neurons. The weight matrix of size (4,255) is because each of the 4 input features is connected to each of the 255 neurons in the dense layer, resulting in a total of 4*255 = 1020 connections.
- The output size of (126976,255) is because for each of the 126976 samples, there are 255 neurons in the dense layer, each producing an output.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I now understand the Dense Layer more!!!

Comment: Happy to help you!